# How to use prism.js to display codes in blazor page(blazor server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I had try to use prism to display code in my blazor page.
Firstly, I edit _Host.cshtml like below

```html
<head>
    ...
    <link href="css/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    ...
    <script src="scripts/prism.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, it didn't work. At the beginning,the Code blocks are all OK. But them flash across, and turnt to what like below.
[image]

But when I run the prasm.js in the Console in Edge, The code blocks turn back. They are what I want.
[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please enter code snippet. We need more details from HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because blazor is a SPA, and therefore doesn't really  like anything modifying the DOM, as the blazor SPA framework likes to control the DOM.

The solution is:

1. Add prism to _Hosts.cshtml.

`<script src="js/prism.js"></script>`

2. Add code to your page to render the prism file.

`
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Prism.highlightAll");
}
```

`

The reason OnAfterRenderAsync is used is so that prism can alter the DOM via the SPA framework after blazor has rendered it.

Comment: Thanks. 2 years has passed since I post this question when I was just a beginner to Web Developent.

Comment: I was looking for the answer myself, found it so thought I’d answer here, apologies it’s a late reply.

Answer (score 2):

an ugly hack

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Prism.highlightAll");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prismjs v1.25.0, there is a "cshtml" language now.